# Android native back button long press

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

I'm trying to target the native back Button on **longpress** event in Android (and after in React-Native).

But, i not see any API on Android docs ? Anyone know if an API is available for listen this event ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding the onKeyLongPress method inside your Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        System.out.println("Back button long pressed");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Note that wont work on Android OS > 9